# Is there a way to access and manage a Slack Workflow as text?

Tags: slack, slack-integration

Slack provides a visual editor for its Workflows, but I need to have all my organizations DevOps under source control (and as text).

Is there a way to access and manage a Slack Workflow as text?

Answer (score 0):

From https://slack.com/features/workflow-automation

> WORKFLOW BUILDER
> Build a better workday, your way
> Get more done, faster. Transform everyday processes into automated workflows, without writing a single line of code.
>
> TALK TO SALES

You might also find helpful to look at

Slack Help Center > Tutorials & videos > Tutorials

[Build a workflow](https://slack.com/help/articles/16962850225939-Build-a-workflow)

It doesn't mention an option to manage workflow as text.

If you are developer look to https://api.slack.com/automation/workflows. In order to understand this doc, you might have to go first to https://api.slack.com/automation/quickstart or even might have to start from https://api.slack.com/:

> Workflows
> Workflows let you create complex and adaptable automations by building chains of functions.
>
> Use your custom functions, pick from pre-defined Slack functions, or combine both to get the workflows you want.